# How to fill an empty space when column numbers are odd?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've a really bad bootstrap issue. I googled hours and days to find a solution for this issue but nothing out there. I have a page with 3 rows and each row with 3 columns in col-md- I've set each column to col-md-4 in col-sm I've set it to col-sm-6 and in col-xs- I've set it to col-xs-6. When I resize the page to sm or xs I end up for each row with 2 columns and a single column in a new row. The same thing happens for the next rows. I know that the problem is that I've used 3 different rows and it's difficult to merge the rows because they are calculated as separate parts by bootstrap. But I've no other choice and have to find a solution for this problem. Please help me and I'll be very thankful.

```
<div class="container-fluid">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c1">
                      <p class="port-desc" style="">
                          <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                      </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c2">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c3">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c4">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c5">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        another text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c6">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c7">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c8">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        asdfasdfasdf<br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6  portcols">
                <div class="port-container c9">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                       <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**The first image is my page in md size and the second is my page in sm size**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put it all in one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have all the columns in 1 row, since you are using 3 columns set to `col-*-4` they will break to new row automatically after every 3 `col-*-4` div's. see fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7oe5kh9L/43/

```
<div class="container-fluid">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c1">
                      <p class="port-desc" style="">
                          <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                      </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c2">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c3">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c4">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c5">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        another text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c6">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c7">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
                <div class="port-container c8">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                        asdfasdfasdf<br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6  portcols">
                <div class="port-container c9">
                    <p class="port-desc" style="">
                       <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                        http://www.asdfasfd.com
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam Buchanan Smith

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to resolve this issue would be to uses a dynamic web page language such as Razor or Jade to check for window size 
(Razor)

```
@{
    var windowSize = "med"
    @if(Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth < 768){
    windowSize = "small"
    }
}


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
            <div class="port-container c4">
                <p class="port-desc" style="">
                    <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                    http://www.asdfasfd.com
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
            <div class="port-container c5">
                <p class="port-desc" style="">
                    <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                    another text
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
@if(windowSize == "small"){
    </div>
    <div class="row">
}
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portcols">
            <div class="port-container c6">
                <p class="port-desc" style="">
                    <span style="font-size: 24px;">asdfasdfasdf</span> <br>
                    http://www.asdfasfd.com
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
@if(windowSize == "med"){
    </div>
    <div class="row">
}
    ...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try it but the second answer is simpler and more practical. Anyway thanks for your response. I didn't work with Razor yet and your answer motivated me to give a look at it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah, that answer is much better. Razor and Jade are super powerful though and worth looking into for solutions to other problems.